# I Can´t Plot a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a python Pandas Series:

```
ts
2017-05-23 17:21:08.557178    3366625
2017-05-23 17:21:08.557178    3353558
Freq: U, dtype: int64
```

when I try to use:

```
ts.plot()
```

My jupyter notebook crashes:

```
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60490 
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60491 
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60492 
200 GET /api/contents/youtube.ipynb?content=0&_=1495574094520 (::1) 556.32ms 
200 PUT /api/contents/youtube.ipynb (::1) 982.61ms 
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5) 
WARNING:root:kernel 9-42bc-b107-48c5a157b0ac 
restarted Starting kernel: ['/anaconda/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel', '-f', '/Users/.../kernel-92...c.json'] 
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60493 
KernelRestarter: restart apparently succeeded
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you expand on "crashes"? Any particular logs generated? Error messages? Etc.

Comment: Jupyter notebook message: Kernel Restarting. The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Comment: [Edit] the question with the details. Also, if that's all the logging you have, run Jupyter Notebook with the `--debug` argument to get more.

Comment: Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60490
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60491
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60492
200 GET /api/contents/youtube.ipynb?content=0&_=1495574094520 (::1) 556.32ms
 200 PUT /api/contents/youtube.ipynb (::1) 982.61ms
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)
WARNING:root:kernel 9-42bc-b107-48c5a157b0ac restarted
Starting kernel: ['/anaconda/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel', '-f', '/Users/.../kernel-92...c.json']
Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:60493
KernelRestarter: restart apparently succeeded

Comment: Again, edit **into the question itself**. Comments are for supplementary discussion -- anything that's essential for purposes of providing an answer needs to be part of the question.

Comment: Also, is that with or without `--debug`?

Comment: jupyter notebook --debug.